# What's the name and equation of the generalization of parabola where the focus is not a point but circle?

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

What's the name and equation of the generalization of parabola where the focus is not a point but circle ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Even if your method is wrong, including it in the question will help us give an answer that is useful to you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the curve you're trying to describe? "The locus of points $P$ such that the distance to ... equals the distance to ..."

Comment: I have never heard of a circle serving as a focus.  Is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_conic) helpful?

Comment: @Shaun The OP is not asking how to solve a problem.  He is asking what the name of a specific mathematical object is.  I feel that your response is therefore inappropriate.

Comment: @MathGeek I feel that my comment to Shaun, above, also applies to you.

Comment: That's a fair point, @user2661923; I'll delete my comment and so on . . .

Comment: How can a focus not be a point?  Are you referring to a *sphere*, which projects parallel light on its axis to a so-called "blur spot"?  Please specify clearly what this "circle" refers to.  And do you mean instead a *disk*??

Comment: @user2661923 Finding the equation of something requires a method, so I disagree with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line is entirely outside the circle, you have a parabola!

If $P$ is equidistant at distance $d$ from a line and from a circle with radius $r$, with the line completely outside the circle, then the distance from $P$ to the center of the is $d+r$. If we move the line back away from the circle by a displacement if $r$ that distance from $P$ also becomes $d+r$. Thereby the definition of a parabola is satisfied.